# Solr 4.6.1 Streaming Solr Servers Error

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

After moving from Solr 4.4 to Solr 4.6.1, I am getting the below Exception while updating my Indexes using the Data Import Handler.  Does anybody have any ideas on why this is happening?

```
ERROR - 2014-02-18 09:39:35.232; org.apache.solr.update.StreamingSolrServers$1; error
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request



request: http://10.200.131.174:8080/solr/collection1/update?update.distrib=FROMLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2F10.200.131.173%3A8080%2Fsolr%2Fcollection1%2F&wt=javabin&version=2
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:240)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
ERROR - 2014-02-18 09:39:35.244; org.apache.solr.update.StreamingSolrServers$1; error
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request
```

Comment: This also happens on a solr 5.5.0

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue for Solr versions greater than 4.5. I too ran into this while running SolrCloud with 2 shards. It seems that the update works fine on the server running DIH, but fails when it is forwarded to another shard or replica.

Here's the related [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5551) issue. And [here's another unlucky soul](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Cloud-error-with-shard-update-td4106260.html#a4106269) like you and I who also faced this error.

As far as I know, the only workaround currently is to go back to a Solr version 4.5 or below...

Comment: I don't think that the issue you refer pertains to this situation. I think that the jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6771 is more relevant.